# program not displaying first operand after change of data type

Tags: c

I'm currently teaching myself a little C and am receiving a curious response from the executable. Here is the code.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   int a, b;   /* the operands in the arithmetic */

   while(1) {
      printf("\n\n\n enter two integers: ");
      scanf("%d %d", &a, &b);
      printf("\n %d  +     %d is  %d", a, b, a + b);
      printf("\n %d  -     %d is  %d", a, b, a - b);
      printf("\n %d  *     %d is  %d", a, b, a * b);
      printf("\n %d  /     %d is  %d", a, b, a / b);
      printf("\n %d  mod   %d is  %d", a, b, a % b);
   }
   return 0;
}
```

When this is run, using the int data type as shown, it produces the following output.

enter two integers: `32000 32000`

```
32000 + 32000 is 64000
32000 - 32000 is 0
32000 * 32000 is 1024000000
32000 / 32000 is 1
32000 mod 32000 is 0
```

As you can see the output is as would be expected. However when int is replaced with short and no other changes have been made the program generates the following output.

enter two integers: `32000 32000`

```
0 + 32000 is 32000
0 - 32000 is -32000
0 * 32000 is 0
0 / 32000 is 0
0 mod 32000 is 0
```

As you can clearly see the program no longer displays the first operand even though 32000 is within the range that gcc documentation says can be represented by a short, which is -32767 to 32767. I am at a loss to understand this.

Further research has revealed that, with the scanf() function, I should have used included the format specification modifier h replacing %d with %hd. My understanding is that using only %d with scanf() causes either the compiler or the hardware to "throw away" the top two bytes.

What I am really puzzled about is why is it that only the first operand is affected considering that scanf() used two instances of the (incorrect) %d format specifier ?

Any help that you may be able to give with this would be much appreciated.

Best regards,

Stuart

Comment: Learn from a good C book, not from online tutorials. The tutorials are good for reference, but will always make you a c programmer with lot of holes.

Comment: Hi Ashish, Thanks for the reply. I am teaching myself from a book. It's "C Through UNIX" by Kenneth E. Martin. It's admittedly an older book but does require me think a bit more about relationships within the language. In this case, the relationship between a data type used in a declaration and the most appropriate format specifier to use, as well as what that means for how RAM is used. Thanks also for the hint about tutorials. I'll bear that in mind.

Answer (score 3):

The compiler cannot give you the correct result because you **lied** to it (by using the wrong format specifier).

If you want to enter a `int`, use `"%d"`; If you want to enter a `short int`, use `"%hd"`.

Otherwise, you will cause undefined behavior, in which case anything from a segfault to a run-time crash can take place. Keep in mind that undefined behaviors don't deserve a discussion.

Answer (score 0):

I think that when a value for the second variable `b` is entered the memory occupied by variable `a` is overwritten or vice versa.

It is the same effect that the memory around an array can be overwritten if to use an invalid index out of the acceptable range of indices for the array.